# Get cell index from cell value, Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
Environment    Status    Version    PatchNumber
Windows        Live      1.0        2
Unix           Live      2.0        4
Mac            Live      1.3        8
```

If I have the above shown data in an excel, how do I access the cellNumber of PatchNumber using the text

`XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();`
I would like to access `row.getCellNumber("PatchNumber");` //Note this method does not exist in Apache POI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I understand what you're after - you want to know which column contains the word "Patch" in it's first row? If so, all you need to do is something like:

```
Sheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row r = s.getRow(0);

int patchColumn = -1;
for (int cn=0; cn<r.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {
   Cell c = r.getCell(cn);
   if (c == null || c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
       // Can't be this cell - it's empty
       continue;
   }
   if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
      String text = c.getStringCellValue();
      if ("Patch".equals(text)) {
         patchColumn = cn;
         break;
      }
   }
}
if (patchColumn == -1) {
   throw new Exception("None of the cells in the first row were Patch");
}
```

Just loop over the cells in the first (header) row, check their value, and make a note of the column you're on when you find your text!

Comment: I too am using the same technique in my code, just wanted to know if there was an API provided by Apache POI to do the same. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Nope. Everyone's requirements for finding things in worksheets will differ, and there's nothing special about the first row, so there's nothing general that would work from everyone. Best bet is to do the few lines of coding yourself, covering your specific requirements!

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this what you want?

```
row.getCell(3)
```

> public XSSFCell getCell(int cellnum) Returns the cell at the given (0
>   based) index, with the Row.MissingCellPolicy from the parent Workbook.

If you want to access exactly by name - "PatchNumber" you can read header row and save an index of PatchNumber. I think the table model only defines access to cells, but doesn't provide associate access by column names. All rows are equal in model I think :-)

To get column index. I would iterate over header row and build a list of column names `columns` then you can use `columns.indexOf("PatchNumber")`

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#getCell(int)

Comment: getcell(int x) is to return the cell. I wanted the cellNumber, in my case patchNumber today lies in column 4, tomorrow it might move to column 5 or 3, so wanted to know if I can get the index of the column via the column text.

Comment: This is not possible obviously. The row doesn't know about header row. Did you tried to read header row?

Comment: I couldn't find any API's, and now since @Vladimir says its not possible I am assuming that such an API doesn't exist in Apache POI.

Comment: @SDS, Correct. Apache POI only provides API to iterate over rows and cells. But getting column index is a logic which depends on your document. So you will have to iterate over header row to get the desired result. Does this answer your question now?

Comment: yes I ended up writing code to get the same. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
public CellAddress searchStringInXslx(String string) throws IOException{
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("Books.xlsx");
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
            CellAddress columnNumber=null;

            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                 Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                 Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                 while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                     Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                     if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){ 
                         String text = cell.getStringCellValue();
                          if (string.equals(text)) {
                             columnNumber=cell.getAddress();
                             break;
                          }
                        }
                     }
            }
            workbook.close();
            return columnNumber;
     }
```

Comment: this method will return the cell address of the searched string.